# Speeding up webscraping in selenium

Tags: python, json, selenium, web-scraping, request

I wrote small app which is taking prices of Reserved Instances from AWS site and then printing name of the instance and its price (I want to have only Convertible 3-year term). App works. However, it is working very slow, probably because the list allElements contains 1925 elements and later I am iterating through all of its elements. I would like to filter the data like in the code (let's take only Linux instances which name starts with c5). How to do it faster? Is there any chance to speed up with filtering on place and do not put everything from this site to allElements list? Thank you in advance for help!

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import time

caps = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
#caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "normal"  #  complete
#caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "eager"  #  interactive
caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "none"
browser = webdriver.Firefox(desired_capabilities=caps)
browser.get('https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/reserved-instances/pricing/')
delay=3

time.sleep(10)

#browser.find_element_by_link_text('Windows').click()

try:
    myElem = WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'aws-plc-content')))
    print ("Page is ready!")
except TimeoutException:
    print ("Loading took too much time!")

time.sleep(2)

allElements=browser.find_elements_by_class_name("aws-pricing-table-wrapper")


for el in allElements:
    lista=el.text.split("\n")
    indeks=lista.index("CONVERTIBLE 3-YEAR TERM")
    prices=lista[indeks+2]
    if lista[0].startswith('c5'):
        print(lista[0])
        print(prices.split()[4])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried with Chrome driver and I hope we will get the same result on FF as well.

You need to do couple of things to achieve that.

1. Infinite loop and Scroll the page first
2. Find_all elements using `WebDriverWait` and append into list while checking no duplicates in the list
3. Once it will reach bottom of the it will break from the loop.
4. Use following XPATH which give output you are after.
5. Use `element.get_attribute("textContent")` to get the value if you use `element.text` you might end up with some blank string.

Try Below code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import time


browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/reserved-instances/pricing/')
delay=10

try:
    myElem = WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.aws-plc-content')))
    print ("Page is ready!")
except TimeoutException:
    print ("Loading took too much time!")

last_height = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
items=[]
while True:
    browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.END)
    time.sleep(1)

    allElements = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(
        (By.XPATH, "//div[@class='aws-pricing-table-wrapper']/h2[starts-with(text(),'c5.')]")))
    print(len(allElements))
    for el in allElements:

        if el.text in items:
            continue

        items.append(el.get_attribute("textContent").strip())
        items.append(el.find_element_by_xpath("./following-sibling::table[4]//tr//th[contains(.,'Convertible 3-Year Term')]/following::tbody[1]//tr[1]//td[4]").get_attribute("textContent").strip())

    new_height = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height

#Print all items and their price.
print(items)
#Get the length of the list #it should be 244X2
print(len(items))
```

**Output On console:**

```
Page is ready!
9
88
['c5.large', '$0.041', 'c5.xlarge', '$0.081', 'c5.2xlarge', '$0.162', 'c5.4xlarge', '$0.324', 'c5.9xlarge', '$0.729', 'c5.12xlarge', '$0.985', 'c5.18xlarge', '$1.459', 'c5.24xlarge', '$1.970', 'c5.metal', '$1.970', 'c5.large', '$0.101', 'c5.xlarge', '$0.141', 'c5.2xlarge', '$0.292', 'c5.4xlarge', '$0.454', 'c5.9xlarge', '$0.859', 'c5.12xlarge', '$1.115', 'c5.18xlarge', '$1.589', 'c5.24xlarge', '$2.100', 'c5.metal', '$2.100', 'c5.large', '$0.074', 'c5.xlarge', '$0.114', 'c5.2xlarge', '$0.195', 'c5.4xlarge', '$0.357', 'c5.9xlarge', '$0.762', 'c5.12xlarge', '$1.018', 'c5.18xlarge', '$1.492', 'c5.24xlarge', '$2.003', 'c5.metal', '$2.003', 'c5.large', '$0.133', 'c5.xlarge', '$0.265', 'c5.2xlarge', '$0.530', 'c5.4xlarge', '$1.060', 'c5.9xlarge', '$2.385', 'c5.12xlarge', '$3.193', 'c5.18xlarge', '$4.771', 'c5.24xlarge', '$6.386', 'c5.metal', '$6.386', 'c5.large', '$0.613', 'c5.xlarge', '$0.745', 'c5.2xlarge', '$1.490', 'c5.4xlarge', '$2.980', 'c5.9xlarge', '$6.705', 'c5.12xlarge', '$8.953', 'c5.18xlarge', '$13.411', 'c5.24xlarge', '$17.906', 'c5.metal', '$17.906', 'c5.large', '$0.200', 'c5.xlarge', '$0.333', 'c5.2xlarge', '$0.665', 'c5.4xlarge', '$1.331', 'c5.9xlarge', '$2.994', 'c5.12xlarge', '$4.004', 'c5.18xlarge', '$5.988', 'c5.24xlarge', '$8.008', 'c5.metal', '$8.008', 'c5.xlarge', '$1.765', 'c5.2xlarge', '$3.530', 'c5.4xlarge', '$7.060', 'c5.9xlarge', '$15.885', 'c5.12xlarge', '$21.193', 'c5.18xlarge', '$31.771', 'c5.24xlarge', '$42.386', 'c5.metal', '$42.386', 'c5.large', '$0.521', 'c5.xlarge', '$0.561', 'c5.2xlarge', '$1.122', 'c5.4xlarge', '$2.244', 'c5.9xlarge', '$5.049', 'c5.12xlarge', '$6.745', 'c5.18xlarge', '$10.099', 'c5.24xlarge', '$13.490', 'c5.metal', '$13.490', 'c5.large', '$0.108', 'c5.xlarge', '$0.149', 'c5.2xlarge', '$0.297', 'c5.4xlarge', '$0.595', 'c5.9xlarge', '$1.338', 'c5.12xlarge', '$1.796', 'c5.18xlarge', '$2.676', 'c5.24xlarge', '$3.592', 'c5.metal', '$3.592', 'c5.xlarge', '$1.581', 'c5.2xlarge', '$3.162', 'c5.4xlarge', '$6.324', 'c5.9xlarge', '$14.229', 'c5.12xlarge', '$18.985', 'c5.18xlarge', '$28.459', 'c5.24xlarge', '$37.970', 'c5.metal', '$37.970']
176
```

---

**Solution 2:**

If you go to Network Tab You will get following API

> https://a0.p.awsstatic.com/pricing/1.0/ec2/region/us-east-2/reserved-instance/linux/index.json?

Which return results in `json()` format.

```
import requests
res=requests.get("https://a0.p.awsstatic.com/pricing/1.0/ec2/region/us-east-2/reserved-instance/linux/index.json?",verify=False).json()
for item in res['prices']:

    if 'c5.' in item['attributes']['aws:ec2:instanceType']:
        if item['attributes']['aws:offerTermLeaseLength']=="3yr" and item['attributes']['aws:offerTermOfferingClass'] =="convertible" and item['attributes']['aws:offerTermPurchaseOption']=="No Upfront":
           print(item['attributes']['aws:ec2:instanceType'])
           print('$' + str(item['calculatedPrice']['effectiveHourlyRate']['USD']))
```

**Output**:

```
c5.xlarge
$0.08100000000000002
c5.18xlarge
$1.4589999999999999
c5.4xlarge
$0.32400000000000007
c5.2xlarge
$0.16200000000000003
c5.24xlarge
$1.97
c5.9xlarge
$0.729
c5.metal
$1.97
c5.12xlarge
$0.985
c5.large
$0.041
```

[image]

Comment: It works but not to the end :) The prices are not correct for each instance :(

Comment: what should be price value for `c5.large` can you mentioned for example?

Comment: For all of the instances price should be taken from Convertible 3-year term and Effective Hourly No Upfront, so for example for c5.large it should be $0.041

Comment: There is easy of getting that value without selenium using python request module if you wish I can post that answer as well.

Comment: Sure if you can :) I would lke to learn another webscrapping tool beside selenium. This solution will be also faster than this?

Comment: @Lukasz : Api is not giving the value you are looking after,I guess AWS location issue.I will comeback to you shortly.

Comment: @Lukasz : Can you try Edited Scripts.

Comment: @Lukasz : Updated the python request option as well.

Comment: @Kanduk : Thank you very much for your time and efforts! It works perfectly and fast. I'm just curious how did you find this API on AWS site? :)

Comment: As I mentioned If you go to Network Tab and got to XHR tab then do Ctrl+R it retrieve lots of API you have to choose linux one.Check the attached snapshot.

Comment: Ah yes I didn't even see that there is Network Tab when I was checking the source code. I am new to webscrapping :) Thank you one more time!